# Library or protocol to allow streaming music across LAN?

Tags: ios, streaming, lan

are there any libraries or open protocols to allow for sending music bitstreams across multiple machines in a LAN?

Answer (score 0):

If you want everyone to be listening to the same content like a radio station, try streaming from a media server. Then create a page with an embedded player for a channel on your media server. Then publish the page.

Be prepared for high data usage as each connected user will increase data consumption by 1 x the bitrate.